# chordDiagram: color gradients for links between groups

Tags: r, chord-diagram, circlize

My question is about the function 'chordDiagram' of the 'circlize' package in R.
I wonder if there is a possibility to color the links between the different groups with a smooth color gradient of the two groups.
We set the colors of the groups with the 'grid.col' argument and the colors of the links with the 'col' argument.

Is there a way, for each link to get a smooth gradient between the two colors set in grid.col for the 2 groups?
I've seen that this is doable in other programs than R but I wonder if anyone has already faced the same issue.
Here is an example of what I am trying to obtain.
[Example of smooth gradients between groups]

[image]

Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Comment: Seems not to be documented at https://jokergoo.github.io/circlize_book/book/the-chorddiagram-function.html

Comment: Yes, I have carefully read this tutorial before but it's indeed not documented there.